# GL_DEPTH_TEST does not work in OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-testing

I am writing a simple rendering program using OpenGL 3.3.

I have following lines in my code (which should enable depth test and culling):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not set OpenGL depth testing options");

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not set OpenGL culling options");
```

However after rendering I see the following result:

[image: flower-bad-depth]

As you can see the depth test does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Where I should look for the problem?

Some information that may be useful:

- In the projection matrix I have near clipping plane set to 0.2 and far to 3.2 (so near plane is not zero).
- I render mesh and texture it using simple method with glDrawArrays and two buffers for vertex and texture coordinates. Shaders than are used to display these arrays properly.
- I do not calculate and draw normals.
- Context creation code: http://pastebin.com/mRMUxPL1

**UPDATE:**

Finally got it working! As it turns out I was not creating the buffer for depth rendering.
When I replaced this code (buffers initialization):

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &mainFrameBufferId);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBufferId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                      GL_RGBA8,
                      camera.imageSize.width,
                      camera.imageSize.height);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mainFrameBufferId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                          GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                          renderBufferId);
CV_Assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
```

with this one:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &mainFrameBufferId);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBufferId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                      GL_RGBA8,
                      camera.imageSize.width,
                      camera.imageSize.height);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mainFrameBufferId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                          GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                          renderBufferId);
CV_Assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderBufferId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                      GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
                      camera.imageSize.width,
                      camera.imageSize.height);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferId);
```

everything started to work fine!

Comment: Did you request a depth buffer from the OS when you created your context?  Post your context creation code.

Comment: Maybe not... I am new to OpenGL so I can do something incorrectly. Added context creation code to the question.

Comment: Also, are you clearing the depth buffer to the appropriate value?

Comment: Edit that code into the question.  Pastebins die, SO is forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static int visualAttribs[] = { None };
                               ^^^^
int numberOfFramebufferConfigurations = 0;
GLXFBConfig* fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig( display, DefaultScreen(display), visualAttribs, &numberOfFramebufferConfigurations );
CV_Assert(fbConfigs != 0);
```

[`glXChooseFBConfig()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml):

> `GLX_DEPTH_SIZE`: Must be followed by a nonnegative minimum size specification. If this value is zero, frame buffer configurations with **no depth buffer** are preferred. Otherwise, the largest available depth buffer of at least the minimum size is preferred. **The default value is 0.**

Try setting `visualAttribs[]` to something like `{ GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, None }`

Comment: Your answer helped me to find the problem so I'll accept it. Thank you!